# How to prevent app to start from Login screen if user is already logged in using onGenerateRoute Routes

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm using onGenerateRoute for navigation in the app with data so as user start app first time there will be a login screen where user can log in as the user logged in I have saved isLogin to true in local storage as user start app again I want to simply redirect him to the profile screen.

I tried to get value of the isLogin that return in Future as value returns it already on Login page not navigating to ProfileScreen.

```
switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        storage.ready.then((s) async {
          var isLogin = storage.getItem('isLogin');
          isLogin = isLogin ?? false;
          print(isLogin);
          if (isLogin) {
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SampleScreen());
          }
          isLogin
              ? MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SampleScreen())
              : MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());
        });
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => LoginScreen());

      case '/sample':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => SampleScreen());
      case '/profile':
        if (args is List) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => ProfileScreen(userInfo: args),
          );
        }
        return _errorRoute();
      default:
        return _errorRoute();
    }

i think it should execute the storge function before moving next.
```

Comment: can you show the code for the whole build method?

Comment: Build method is very simple.```Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/',
      onGenerateRoute: RouteGenerator.generateRoute,
    );
  }```